# How to subtract two readonly array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, readonly

We know we can't concat readonly array in Typescript,
But we can do this

```
readonly ArrA = [1, 2, 3] as const;
readonly ArrB = [4, 5] as const;
readonly Arr = [...ArrA, ...ArrB];
```

So addition is done, how about subtraction?
ps: If not readonly, we can do this

```
ArrA.filter(n => !ArrB.includes(n));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includes` will be available (irrespective of readonly) if you add "ES7" to `compilerOptions.lib` in `tsconfig.json`.

---

If you care about type-safety at the array member level, you can do something like:

```
const ArrA = [1, 2, 3] as const;
const ArrB = [3, 4, 5] as const;

// Aliases for tuple-member types
type ArrAMember = typeof ArrA[number] // (1 | 2 | 3)
type ArrBMember = typeof ArrB[number] // (3 | 4 | 5)

type ExclusionListMember = Exclude<ArrAMember, ArrBMember> // (1 | 2)

// Type-guard to verify exclusion
function isExcludedByB(i: ArrAMember): i is ExclusionListMember {
    return !ArrB.includes(i as any)
}

const ArrC = ArrA.filter(isExcludedByB)
//    ^ (1 | 2)[]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways you can do this (Subtraction):

The `filter` function runs over the elements of `a1` and it reduce it (but in a new array) to elements who are in `a1` (because we're iterating over it's elements) and are missing in `a2`.

Elements in `a2` which are missing in `a1` won't be included in the result array (subtraction) as the filter function doesn't iterate over the `a2` elements:

```
readonly a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'] as const;
readonly a2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] as const;

let subtraction= a1.filter(item => a2.indexOf(item) < 0);
console.log(subtraction); // Output --> ["e", "f", "g"]
```

You can also do this using lodash:

```
_.difference(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
```

Hope this gives you some insights. Thanks.